# Inner product of Tensors

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, tensor, dot-product, numpy-einsum

Can someone please explain me how to do inner product of two tensors in python to get one dimensional array. For example, I have two tensors with size (6,6,6,6,6) and (6,6,6,6). I need an one dimensional array of size (6,1) or (1,6).

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has a function `tensordot`, check it out:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html